# Integrate windows active directory PHP web application

Tags: php, windows, web-applications, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have created an PHP based web app, but the client user authentication requirement needs windows Active Directory authentications system & role permissions. Can you anyone please help me with how to integrate AD to PHP application?

Comment: I think you're looking for LDAP http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php

Comment: I exactly don't know about LDAP but is it the way to do the integration?